# Can you display a column value using CASE

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I am selecting several columns from TABLB1.

One column (`POST_DATE`) I want to display as '`9999-99-99`' only if the (DB2) value is '`0001-01-01`', otherwise I want it to display the actual DB2 value.

This works fine:

```
  ,CASE 
       WHEN POST_DATE = '0001-01-01' THEN '9999-99-99' 
   ELSE  'NOT 0001-01-01'  END  AS POSTING_DATE
```

This does NOT work:

```
  ,CASE 
       WHEN POST_DATE = '0001-01-01' THEN '9999-99-99' 
   ELSE  POST_DATE  END  AS POSTING_DATE
```

Is there a way to do this in SPUFI?

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression returns a single value -- in your case either a date or a string.  If the `CASE` returns both, then a string is chosen.

So, convert explicitly:

```
(CASE WHEN POST_DATE = '0001-01-01' THEN '9999-99-99' 
      ELSE  CASt(POST_DATE AS VARCHAR(255)
 END) AS POSTING_DATE
```

Alternatively you can use a valid value for a date, instead of `'9999-99-99'`.